# Unable to load data using Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a csv data in the following format:

```
id,name,price,information
12,Pants,50.00,{Clothes & Shoes: 5}
```

And here is my pig script:

```
grunt> sample = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage (',') AS (id:int, name:chararray, price:double, information:chararray);
```

The problem is, when I load information as chararray, because I can't access the category or the quantity itself. I tried to do something like:

`information:tuple(category:chararray, quantity:int)`

But it didn't work..

What should I do?
What is the best way to load information so I can have access to both category and quantity..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a Bag and not a Tuple.[See here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#relations) for Bag,Tuple.

(  ) A tuple is enclosed in parentheses ( ).

{  } An inner bag is enclosed in curly brackets { }.

You can load it like this

```
sample = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage (',') AS (id:int, name:chararray, price:double, information:bag{});
```